# Why line graph is a proper subclass of claw-free graph?

Tags: graphs

A **claw** is the graph isomorphic to $K_{1,3}$, that is, a star graph with three edges, three leaves, and one central vertex. (see below)

[image]

A graph is **claw-free** if it does not contain a claw as an induced subgraph.

The **line graph** of G is the intersection graph of the edges of G, that represents the adjacencies between edges of G.

A graph $F$ is a line graph if there exists a graph $H$ such that $L(H) = F$.

[image]

**My question** is why are line graphs a subclass of claw-free graphs??
**Thanks a lot!**

Comment: What have you tried?  Have you tried to find a graph $H$ such that $L(H) = K_{1,3}$?  There are only so many possibilities for $H$, so you should be able to try them all.  What happens when you do that?

Comment: I'm confused. Even the line graph in the picture shown contains claws.

Comment: @Billiska "Claw-free" means no _induced_ subgraphs are claws. I've edited to correct the definition in the question.

Comment: @Billiska No, is not a claw.....

Comment: oh. never mind. induced by vertex. not induced by edge. Yes, I was going insane. thanks.

Comment: line graphs are claw-free graphs, so line graphs is a subclass of claw-free graphs, but don't know why the former is proper subclass of the latter??

Comment: "why the former is proper subclass ". This is a different question from the one you asked originally. Please create a new question if you want to know something other than your original question. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is answered on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Claw-free_graph#Examples):

> "Line graphs may be characterized in terms of nine forbidden subgraphs;<sup>[2]</sup> the claw is the simplest of these nine graphs."

The reference is to the following paper:

> [2] Beineke, L. W. (1968), "Derived graphs of digraphs", in Sachs, H.; Voss, H.-J.; Walter, H.-J., Beiträge zur Graphentheorie, Leipzig: Teubner, pp. 17–33.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_graph#/media/File:Forbidden_line_subgraphs.svg) contains a pictorial description of these nine graphs. One of them is $K_5^-$, obtained from $K_5$ by removing a single edge.

If you take any of the other forbidden subgraphs then you get a claw-free graph which isn't a line graph.

Comment: Thank you very much. Wow, I am a slow learner, it takes me time to understand the answer...:-) I am now working on it.....